# How open Gstreamer raw file?

Tags: gimp, image-editing, gstreamer, camera-raw, yuv

I want to capture *RAW* picture from webcam, But I do not want to use *JPG*, Because it makes the picture bad and full of noise.

I can shoot a *RAW* video using this code, and also can open the file using *VLC* without any problems.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

Also i can shoot a *RAW* picture using this code.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 ! filesink location=test.raw
```

But the problem is that the file does not open using a photo editor such as *GIMP*.

[*RAW YUV 4:2:2* file you can download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TWsyXkE8CVTtkWb9AgmO5Xn1kni-T2vs)

My OS is *Ubuntu*.

Is the problem in the *Gstreamer*? (Maybe need to convert picture, but without loss details, How?)

Is the problem in the *GIMP*? (Maybe does not support *RAW*, what alternative?)

Answer (score 0):

*PNG* is lossless formate, so maybe ther's no difference between *RAW* and *PNG* except *PNG* file size is smaller than *RAW* file size.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! pngenc snapshot=false compression-level=1 ! filesink location=img-test.png
```